# Make an array of id's of a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, model

My question is simple... or so it seems. If `@set.cards` retrieves "id", "front", "back", "created_at" (etc.). How do I get just an array of the id's? `[1,2,3,4,5...etc]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
@set.cards.map(&:id)
```

Comment: Because they both answered 10 mins ago, I'd go with the guy with the lower reputation score.

Answer (score 5):

Rails provides a standard method for this:

```
@set.card_ids
```

Reference: The `has_many` [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many). Look at the 5th method from the top, i.e. `collection_singular_ids`.

Comment: +1 this is the way I would do it too as long as it's only the id's you want. Other columns require the map syntax